# Laravel Softdelete with foreign key and restrict constraints?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I was wondering how to use **Laravels softdelete** with something like MySql **foreign key restrict** constraints.

Is there already something build into the framework? Softdelete is already working but I need some kind of validation to related models. e.g. an error message to the user "You cannot delete this item because it hast 5 related records"

Thanks,

Comment: Did you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There's is no build in solution for "unpluging" DB relation on soft delete.

What You can do for example is to use observers ([event listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events)) or use [eloquent model events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) for example `deleting`/`deleted` like:

```
public function boot()
{
    User::deleted(function ($user) {
        if ($user->deleted_at) {
            // here You have to unplug all the dependencies
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using the `deleting` event. Even though the model is using soft deletes, the `deleting`/`deleted` events are still used. Additionally, sounds like OP may want to prevent the delete, so the before event would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes you could, but I think that for soft deletes safer is to use `saving`/`saved` to be sure (you set this date somewhere else)

Comment: Do the `saving`/`saved` events get called when you soft delete a record? Looking at the code, it looks like the soft delete is performed using an update on the query builder, meaning the `saving`/`saved` events would not be called.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, in Laravel they have soft delete models.To use this `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` trait on the model and add the `deleted_at` column to your `$dates` property.

They also have their Querying Soft Deleted Models.You can choose anyone.

You can get all documentation about this in **[here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#deleting-models)**

Comment: Softdelete is already working. But ignores the mysql key constraints, because the item is not really deleted.

Comment: "You cannot delete this item because it hast 5 related records" for this you can do this with javascript.